# Proof help involving squeeze theorem and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So I need to prove that if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to A$, $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to A$, and $a_n\le c_n \le b_n$, that $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to A$.

So I basically let $\epsilon$ > 0 and used the definition of a limit to say that $-\epsilon < a_n - A < \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon < b_n - A < \epsilon$ but then I don't really understand how to use these two facts to get $c_n$ squeezed in the middle. Is there a $\max$ or $\min$ function involved? If so, can someone explain how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_1$ such that $$n\ge N_1\implies |a_n-A|<\epsilon.$$ Also, there exists $N_2$ such that $$n\ge N_2\implies |b_n-A|<\epsilon.$$ But, $$a_n\le c_n\le b_n\implies |c_n-A|\le \max\{|a_n-A|,|b_n-A|\}.$$ Thus, if $n\ge \max \{N_1,N_2\}$ it is

$$|c_n-A|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: The expression $\min\{|a_n - A|, |b_n - A|\}$ should instead be $\max\{|a_n - A|, |b_n - A|\}$.

Comment: @kobe You are right. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, then there are $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that: if $n > N_1 \Rightarrow a_n > A - \epsilon$, and if $n > N_2 \Rightarrow c_n < A + \epsilon$. Thus if you choose $N_3 = \text{max($N_1,N_2$)}$, then if $n > N_3$, then: $A-\epsilon < a_n < c_n < b_n < A+\epsilon \Rightarrow A-\epsilon < c_n < A+\epsilon \Rightarrow |c_n-A| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = A$.